# Threading and tcp/ip connections problems

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp

I'm new in python and threading so please be indifferent. I'm trying to do 2-players game in python. Data are send through tcp/ip protocol (client-server architecture). On server I have three threads. One comunicate with one user, second with second and in third thread I'm getting data which was send by client form two others threads. This data are used to check if game is over. And it's all working good. Problems start now. When the game is over I want to send another data to client. So Thread 3 need to send data to client, but two others threads are still working and they still have connections with clients. Generally I do not know how to do this. I tried to send information through the Queue from third thread to others that they should close theirs connections. It's thread class code:

```
class myThread(threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, threadID, name, conn, conn2, kto, wartosc, 
wybor,kolejkaZadan,gracz1,gracz2):
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)
       self.threadID = threadID
       self.name = name
       self.conn = conn
       self.conn2 = conn2
       self.kto = kto
       self.wartosc = wartosc
       self.wybor = wybor
       self.kolejkaZadan = kolejkaZadan
       self.gracz1 = gracz1
       self.gracz2 = gracz2

       def run(self):
            if self.wybor == None:       
            toClient(self.conn,self.conn2,self.kto,self.wartosc,self.gracz1)
            else:
               while True:

                 data,kolejkaZwrotna = self.kolejkaZadan.get() // I receive data from two others threads
                 time.sleep(10)
                 dataKolejne,kolejkaZwrotna = self.kolejkaZadan.get() // I receive data from two others threads

                 if data is dataKolejne: // if end
                   tworzenieXmla(self.gracz1, self.gracz2)
                   odczytywanieXmla('itemGracza1',gracz1Otrzymane)

                   plik = open('Marcin.xml', 'rb')

                   czyZamknacConnection = True
                   kolejkaZwrotna.put(czyZamknacConnection) // send data to two others threads 

                   while True:
                      czescXmla = plik.read(10000)

                     #self.conn2.send(czescXmla)
```

And It's my send/receiv function which is executed by two other threads:

```
def toClient(conn, conn2, kto, wartosc,gracz):
 wordsBackup = None
 kolejkaZwrotna = queue.Queue() 

 while True:

    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

    if not data:
        break

    if kolejkaZwrotna.get() is True://receive form thread 3 
        conn2.close()
        print('closed')
        break

    if len(data)>7:
        print('WARNING', data)

    words = str(data.decode()).split()
    #print(words[0], words[1])

    if kto==1:
        conn2.send(data)


    if kto==2:
        conn2.send(data)

    kolejkaZadan.put(words[2],kolejkaZwrotna) // send to thread 3 
    xmlTablicaDoZapisu(str(int(words[0])),str(int(words[1])),str(int(words[2])),gracz)
```

Generally there is no error and we can play but there is only one player on each computer so I think server don't send data. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

A fix for your current situation would be to change all those connection variables into an `array` of connections which you could iterate over. You might want to build some container classes which define their behavior since not all clients are the same ( server client, and player clients ). That way you aren't limited by the amount of variables you've declared, and threads available.
Then once a new client connects you simply add it to the array and your iterator will take care of the rest.

This is a common problem with TCP/IP though, in that you always have to have open connections to `n` clients, which not only takes up resources but since TCP/IP is a queued protocol it could also set the entire game back if any client has a slower connection. In practice your game will always be as laggy as the player with the worst connection.

You have a couple of options.

1. You can have one thread always open which handles connections. Your `supervisor` thread. It holds an array of open connections' data and dispenses actions to the other threads. This isn't the best option since you'll quickly encounter `Race Conditions` such as two threads trying to use the same data.
2. You can switch over to UDP which will leave your threads wide open since there's no persistent connection. You'd then need to send states to each client, and once they `ACK` them you can get rid of the data. The majority of games implement UDP now'a'days, even turn based ones.

Beej's guide is probably the most extensive on the internet about UDP/TCP and socket control theory.
http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html

And there's also Gaffer on Games which is a fantastic resource as well.
http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/udp-vs-tcp/